# getting error when trying to save user Select data

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I am trying to save what state a user select after 'POST' the form action runs on the same page, but I keep getting  unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting '}' error. What am I missing?

I have the following code:

```
<select style='width:50px; float:left; position:relative; left:-160px; top:2px; border-radius:3px; ' project='statelist' class='statelist' name='statelist'>

$state = array( 'AZ','AL','AK','AR', 'CA','CO', 'CT','DE','DC','FL', 'GA', 'HI','ID','IL', 'IN','IA','KS','KY','LA','ME','MT','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC', 'ND','OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'MD','MA', 'MI','MN','MS', 'MO','PA', 'RI', 'SC','SD','TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA','WA', 'WV','WI','WY');

foreach($state as $name) {
$selected = '';
if {$_POST['statelist'] == $name}{
$selected = 'selected';}
echo '<option value="'.$name.'"'.$selected.">{$name}</option>\n";
}
</select>
```

Comment: It seems like the error is in your back end code, not your HTML markup. Show some of that? Where/how is the `POST` processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got too bracket happy.

```
if {$_POST['statelist'] == $name}{
```

should be

```
if ($_POST['statelist'] == $name){
```

Comment: whoa thanks for the fast response I made the change now I get  unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: You're missing a quote in your echo statement.

Comment: have I ever told you I love to concatenate?

Comment: hmmm..it's giving me the error on line 68 which is 
if ($_POST['statelist'] == $name){
if I change it to brackets like orginally posted I get an expected } on line 68...why is this so complicated..it's too late I need to sleep